# Test for strongly typed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc 2 I need to get programatically all the views thar are strongly typed, and show a list for views that are not strongly typed.

How can I do that?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly-typed views inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage. Untyped views inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage. N.B. ViewPage inherits from ViewPage. You would have to load up the compiled assembly containing the views (generated via aspnet_compiler.exe) and then run the following LINQ-to-Objects queries:

```
var stronglyTypedViews = from type in assemblyContainingViews.GetTypes()
                         where typeof(ViewPage<>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                         select type;
var weaklyTypedViews = from type in assemblyContainingViews.GetTypes()
                       where typeof(ViewPage).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                          && !typeof(ViewPage<>).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                       select type;
```

Comment: The compiled assembly is only available at run-time? I'm trying to load the dll with Assembly.LoadFile from a test project that reference the asp.net mvc project, but I can't find any view in that dll

Comment: That's right. The views are typically dynamically compiled, but they can be pre-generated via the aspnet_compiler.exe, which ships with the .NET Framework. Take a look at this post for more info: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html